# splitting a bulky file

Tags: c, file

I want to split a 261MB file into 64MB chunks. I have done it but it takes about 15-16 seconds when I read original file and write it into my parts characterwise. Is there a better and optimised way to do that.
Thanks in advance.

---

I now have come to 3 sec by reading and writing in blocks of 256MB.Can it still be optimised

Comment: Unsure of exactly what you are doing, but have you considered using the read() system call instead of the C I/O library?

Comment: ok I can use read to read the file and for writing it to the part?

Comment: read() in the stream and write() out what comes in from the stream and cap the size of the file and then give write() a new file descriptor, until read() reaches EOF.

Comment: what benfit will I get by using read and write system calls? Will it save time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you are reading with `fgetc` and writing with `fputc`, then replacing these with `fread` and `fwrite` to process data in bigger chunks (try 4KB and upwards) will result in a big speedup.